# Trying to split a large .pdf into multiple files. (python, pdftk)

Tags: python, split, bookmarks, pdftk

I've written a script in Python that will split a .pdf by chapter/bookmark. Here is essentially the crux of my program:

```
for each chapter:
    system('pdftk A=file.pdf cat A{start}-{end} output file2.pdf')
```

The toolkit works lovely, but invoking it over and over is obviously not a time-efficient task. Parsing a 200mb .pdf file takes a solid 15-20 seconds, and doing so over the span of some 30 individual chapters takes a *long time*. More time is spent opening the file than actually writing any data.

Since there doesn't seem to be an inherent way to string multiple commands within the toolkit, is there any memory trickery I can pull in Python or the CMD that will let me get around this (i.e. keep the .pdf open)? I'll look at another module, too, if you can suggest one ([pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/) has its own slew of problems though).

Comment: You could crunch it all into a shell file?

Comment: Windows, and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the pdf file in memory, read it into a `StringIO` buffer and tell pdftk to read from stdin. Specifically: Use `subprocess.call` instead of `os.system`, with your `StringIO` buffer as the `stdin` argument:

```
mybuffer = StringIO.StringIO(open('file.pdf').read())
subprocess.call('pdftk ...', stdin=mybuffer)
```

It will still need to parse the pdf file anew each time, but at least you won't be spinning your hard drive more than you have to. The only really fast way is to use a tool that can do it in one pass (e.g., solve whatever problems you have with pypdf).

Comment: YES, thank you. stdin was what I was looking for. I couldn't quite get StringIO to work, though, so I'm using open(PDF) as my buffer. Is this horrible etiquette or anything?

Comment: `open(PDF)' is an open filestream, I don't see anything wrong with passing it around. If it works, enjoy it! I'm surprised it gave you a big speedup, though, since you're only getting the limited buffering that the i/o library provides. Are you getting correct output?

Comment: PS. The snippet I included creates a StringIO buffer with your entire file. What couldn't you get to work?

Comment: Yup, seems to work all right. It's not just faster across successive operations, but single ones as well, which leads me to think that something other than having the file in memory is aiding the speedup (pdftk is bad at opening files? dunno).

Comment: This is the error I was getting with StringIO:                                                         
_AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'fileno'_

Comment: Interesting. Something somewhere is trying to access the OS-level file descriptor, which only real open files have. Anyway, glad it works for you now!

Answer (score 0):

If you have for example an `input.pdf` file with 20000 pages and you want to split it in to 1..20.pdf files with 1000 pages each file.

```
for (( i=0; i<=20; i++ )); do let n=$i*1000; let m=$[i+1]*1000; pdftk input.pdf cat $n-$m output $i.pdf; done;
```